# Complete install QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-processing

I using QGIS on Ubuntu and Windows, I have some questions for QGIS on Ubuntu, first I follow official details to install [QGIS on Ubuntu](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html).

On the QGIS on windows I have processing tab to show me toolbox, graphical model and more.

[image: toolbox QGIS on Windows]

In that toolbox I can use algorithms from SAGA GIS,GDAL GRASS GIS and more.

My problem is on the QGIS Ubuntu I dont have that toolbox and algorithms SAGA, GRASS, GDAL, any idea why ?

Any idea how to install QGIS complete to use that algorithms on Ubuntu?

Finally in the plugins I don't have more plugins like with the Windows version, the plugins on QGIS Ubuntu is specific.

Comment: In the plugin manager, is the processing plugin enabled? Furthermore, you need to install SAGA, GRASS, R and other providers to the toolbox manually under Ubuntu. The toolbox is only the interface to those.

Comment: i have install standalone SAGA AND GRASS,how to import manually  on toolbox QGIIS?

Comment: You have to activate them in Processing -> Options. If the processing menu is missing, you have to enable the plugin in the plugin manager. If the plugin manager is empty, the python support is broken.

Comment: i thing so i dont have python support show me Couldn't load SIP module :python disabled.

Comment: Try to install the python-qgis package. It gets missed sometimes during upgrades.

Comment: i have install  `sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

Comment: but not work again

Comment: You have to take care of the messages that come during installation.

Comment: any solution to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You have only to correctly install GRASS and SAGA. After you have installed Qgis:

- for GRASS you have to install the software in this way ([link to official page](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/linux/)):
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install grass`
  and then use this simple workaround ([see here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2017-January/038874.html)):
  `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/grass72 /usr/bin/grass70`
- for SAGA you have to compile the 2.2.3 version because that is supported at the moment, so uninstall all previous version and download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%202.2/SAGA%202.2.3/saga_2.2.3.tar.gz/download) and then compile:
  `./configure
  make
  sudo make install`
  and it will work.

  Remeber to activate GRASS7 and SAGA from Processing option settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the download page http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html and choose to download one of the two:

> OSGeo4W Network Installers (32 bit or 64 bit)

.

This will install everything that you need, without you downloading and installing other stuff manually.

Comment: can i install via OSGeo4W  on Linux ?

Comment: I am not sure, never tried it.

Comment: you can not install via OSGeo4W on Ubuntu for unlucky